# Zoom and morph at the same time using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, merge, zoom

I have two different maps of the same region: one from a distance, the second a close up.

[image: Amazon Basin]

[image: Manaus region]

The white retangle in the first image represents the border of the second image.

I want to apply two effects at once: zoom in on the first image, until the white rectangle occupies the whole image, and morph it with the second image, so when the zoom gets to the final position, the second image will be fully visible.

I managed to apply the zoom, with the command:

```
convert A.png -duplicate 50 -distort SRT '916,401 %[fx:1+0.007*t*t] 0 %[fx:916-(116/50)*t],%[fx:401+(199/50)*t]' t.png
```

This command creates 50 images, which I'll later transform into a video.

Now I have two options: elaborate the first command to make all at once, or apply the morph of the second image to these 50 images. However, I can't find either. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using Linux bash `for`. But I'm sure a pure ImageMagick solution will be way faster.

The 50 images (actually 51) created by the first command are called t-0.png, t-1.png, ... t-50.png.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}..."
mkdir -p blended
for x in {0..50}
do
    blend=$((x*x/25))
    xx="00${x}"
    xx="${xx: -2}"
    composite B.png t-$x.png -blend $blend blended/b-$xx.png
done
cd blended
ffmpeg -framerate 12 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p B.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i b-00.png -t 3 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p A.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i b-50.png -t 5 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p C.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy D.mp4
```

This creates the images b-00.png, b-01.png, ... b-50.png in the previously created "blended" directory, and transforms them into the desired movie clip. The `xx` variable is there to make sure there will be 2 digits, or else `ffmpeg` will create a video using the images in the wrong order.

One problem though: for unknown reasons, b-50.png is slightly darker than B.png, when I think they should look exactly the same.